# I18n and change directions in styles

Tags: sass, vue-i18n

I need to change this "right" to "left" when I18n.locale is equal to 'fn'.
How can I do this??

```
.vgt-compact td:before {
...
float: right}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set class on the element and change the styles depending on that. For example:

```
.vgt-compact 
  td:before {
    ...
    float: right
  }
  &.left td:before {
    ...
    float: left
  }
{
```

and something like this, where `isLeftLocal` is a getter which returns true when `I18n.locale === 'fn'`

```
<div class="vgt-compact" v-bind:class="{ left: isLeftLocal }">...</div>
```